# Jasper reports - Cambodian / Khmer and Laotian Language

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm using Arial Unicode MS to display languages chinese, russian, korean and vietnamese in jasper reports and I export these to pdf using Identity-H for Pdf Encoding.However I can't use this for Cambodian / Khmer and Laotian Language I've tried searching for fonts with no luck. If its possible what type of font and PDF encoding should I use for me to display and embed these languages in PDF.

Update:
I've tried using Khmer OS an Khmer OS System fonts that is already installed in my iReport Designer(3.7.6). These fonts doesn't work and translates the Khmer language into gibberish.

Also tried downloading other Khmer fonts with pdf encoding as Identity-H, doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

At first, look to my research around Khmer Unicode related to iText that is the library using by iReport/Jasper:

- [iText supports Khmer Unicode issue](http://ask.osify.com/qa/613)

I have made a modification on itext to add Khmer render but haven't tried to put that in jasper yet, need more people continue to give some hands ([github](https://github.com/Seuksa/iTextKhmerSample))

**Updated: JasperReport from 6.2 supported**

Thanks to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750736/jasper-reports-cambodian-khmer-and-laotian-language/43868037?noredirect=1#comment74791921_43868037), told us about the JasperReport library update.

It could now convert to pdf from Jasper Report, but still another issue when we mix both English and Khmer, I think we will find a workaround on this.

See my post [here](http://ask.osify.com/qa/868).

Comment: Starting with JasperReports 6.2.0, support for complex/Indic scripts in PDF (by means of AWT text layout) has been added.  It can be seen in the demo/samples/unicode sample, which contains a Khmer text rendered with a Google Noto font.

Comment: Oh, if it is the case, it will be great, I will test it.

Comment: we are using 3.7.6 since we can't use these languages in jasper report, we just used the pdf as images. Downside is, when we put fields the field text may overlap with the image since the image is just static.

Comment: @AlexK, thanks, I edited to get to the point that I wished to explain now.